# SetSelectedItem JCombobox without performing action

Tags: java, swing, events, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox and an event listener(actionPerformed) set on it.

What I want is simple:

- When I select an item with click, I want to perform my event function
- But when I call setSelectedItem(), not to perform event function

Is it possible? How to do that?
Tanks

Comment: It's always a good idea to [search this site](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java&oq=site&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l2j69i65l2.815j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+jcombobox+setselecteditem+turn+off+listener+) before asking what is likely to be a commonly asked question. Luck.

Comment: it's depends on the keywords you give. I've tried with my own words but I dont find this duplicate. Thanks H.F.O.E

Comment: Please look at the link in my comment above for an example of useful key words.

Comment: I say you thanks, that mean that I have already opened your link and see the question you've tagged